# Releasing resources after using app.get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using express().get from node.js to serve GET requests at a specific path. However, at some point I wish to no longer continue serving GET requests at that path. How do I:

1. Stop the server from accepting GET requests at that path.
2. Release all resources I have accumulated.

So here's a simplified version of the problem.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    // do some stuff
    // ...
    // check if we should stop serving requests here
    setInterval(function() {
        if (shouldBeClosed) {
            // what should be here?
        }
    }, 1000);
});

http.listen(8080, function() { });
```

Comment: That answer seems outdated as of Express 4.x. There is no app.routes object as far as I can tell, and the documentation linked to does not include any mention of it either. Presumably it was in the 3.0.5 version.

Comment: Look at ALL the answers. There's on for v4.9.5

Comment: Oh my bad. That looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply start returning a 404 or some other error code...

```
var stop = false;
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    if (!stop) {
        // do some stuff
        // ...
        // check if we should stop serving requests here
        setInterval(function() {
            if (shouldBeClosed) {
                stop = true;
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send('nothing is here any more!');
    }
});
```

As for the second question: what kind of resources do you mean?

Comment: I assume that if I did something like this, the server would treat the path differently than one that never existed. I imagine it still exists in some data structure of paths serving GET requests. So say I create a large number of paths and delete them via this approach, then I imagine I would have a memory leak here.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. This doesn't remove the handler itself. But why would you want to add a large number of paths in the first place? It's difficult to imagine a real scenario where you'd really need this: a large number of different paths, with completely different handlers that have to be unique functions (so you can't use path parameters)...?